# How can user write inside specific cell in TableLayout, so that the user text in the cell gets showed?

Tags: android

I struggle to find out how to allow the user to tap a specific cell inside the table (table layout) and write an input (string) so that it gets shown inside the cell. I would prefer the user to write directly to the cell, instead of inside a input dialog.

I'm fairly new to android studio and this is my first q in stackoverflow. If something needs to be specified, please let me know.

Here is one specific cell in a table row from my xml file:

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#002ED6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0.5dp" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Row1Column1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text=""
            tools:editable="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: If you want user to be allowed to write something you should use EditText instead of TextView. Have a look at the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText)